# Error Converting data type Discount amount vs fixed amount

Tags: sql

Good day

This is the code I am using and it gives an error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"

```
select  InvPrice.StockCode, InvPrice.SellingPrice, 
        SorContractPrice.StartDate, SorContractPrice.ExpiryDate,    SorContractPrice.PriceMethod, SorContractPrice.FixedPrice,          SorContractPrice.Discount1,InvPrice.SellingPrice

From    InvPrice 

Inner Join 
        SorContractPrice
        on SorContractPrice.StockCode = InvPrice.StockCode

where SorContractPrice.PriceMethod IN 
(case when SorContractPrice.PriceMethod = 'F' then SorContractPrice.FixedPrice
            when SorContractPrice.PriceMethod = 'D' then  InvPrice.SellingPrice - SorContractPrice.Discount1
            else SorContractPrice.FixedPrice
            end)
```

I need to deduct the discount from the fixed price alternatively it should stay as the fixed price.

Sorry I am very new to sql

Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to compare different data types. Remove some code and see if the error is still there, if it is then remove some more code etc, until you find the problem construction.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Identify the types of all columns used in the query.  Your error is most likely that `PriceMethod` is a string and the `case` returns a number, but that is just a guess.

Comment: try to convert "SellingPrice" and "Discount1" to same data type.  CAST(SellingPriceAS float) -  CAST( Discount1 as float)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try_convert` on one of the items that you are going to use to minus off. `convert` method works too. [If the first item doesn't work, you can try it on the alternate one. But if you already know which one holds the `varchar` value, then use it on that one.] You can basically convert both of them to the same value (float or numeric)

If you need a short guide on how to use those , here it is : http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/08/try_convert-sql-server-2012-built-in-conversion-function/

But remember that it will not convert it for you if it simply cant. If it can't it just means that the data you are using for `varchar` most likely isn't a number ,etc.

Also, what @KD commented, `cast` also helps too.

Hope this helps you out.